# How to un-initialize a git folder in the root of my pc?

Tags: git, git-init, .git-folder

I am beginner with git. A few weeks ago, I unintentionally created a "git init" on the root of my pc (location: desktop) which means all of my computer files are on that git folder.

How can i delete that git folder, without losing any of my coding or personal files?

Comment: Windows or MacOS?

Comment: Delete the hidden `.git` directory. It's what makes it an initialized git repository.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-init%5D+undo

Answer (score 1):

You should have a hidden folder `.git` in the root directory then. You just have to delete that folder. It will delete only the git repository and leave all of the other files intact.

Comment: Will the .git folder that I delete somehow destroy the other git repositories that are below the root location?

Comment: No, those repositories have their own `.git` folders in their directories and they will stay intact just like the other files.

Answer (score 0):

That's ok, I think that's happenened to any of us haha.

From your terminal, after navigating to your home directory (`cd ~` if on MacOS, `cd \user\username` if on Windows), find the directory of this new project, then you can just run `rm -rf <project-directory-name>`.

If you just want to remove Git from your directory without removing the whole project, you can just remove `.git` at the root directory of it (`cd <project-directory-name>`, then `rm -rf .git`).